# Creating a single file executable from a directory in Windows?

Tags: windows, packages

There's an answer there, but it's two years old, and provides no information on how to do it.

Situation: I have a folder with an executable file, some required dlls and some images.
I want to package all this into a single executable file. If executed, it will run the executable file.

I've found [this superuser post](https://superuser.com/q/428768/320268). However, it doesn't seem to offer a solution.

If you're familiar with Python, there's an application called PyInstaller. It creates single-file executables from python sourcecode.

I'm not sure about the exact inner-workings of it, but it generally does something like this:

- Wrap the directory with executable into a new executable, ex `app.exe`
- the new executable executes a program, which unpacks the hidden directory into a temporary folder, a folder called _MEIxxxxx, x's being numbers. For example: `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI188722`
- execute the program from that folder.

From what I've read, they use hackery dark-magic to make this work. I'm wondering if there is a program that does this kind of dark-magic for non-python files.

Comment: The post you linked doesn't talk about converting a directory into an executable. They talk about storing a directory into a ZIP file, then change its extension, and then they talk about an hypothetical application which is going to be associated to the new extension.

Comment: @drk.com.ar So that would mean, that for example app.newextension would be associated with an application that is already installed on the user's pc, and that would start the program inside the zip? It looks like there really is no way at all to make a self-contained application into an self-contained executable.

Also, I've rewritten the post to be more clear about what I want to achieve.

Comment: Now, your question is different. I'm going to add an answer.

Comment: I suggest creating a MSI file instead.  Windows will automatically install a msi file as well as an exe.  An MSI file is much like an other compressed file (zip etc), but you can configure it to extract and install your app.

Comment: @Azeirah, If the goal is to create a self contained application with just an EXE file, you should consider that this can be achieved at compile-time. You can statically link libraries to avoid having DLLs, you can include arbitrary binary data for resources, you can rely on windows runtime DLLs that exist in System32 for all Windows users as well. If you're not the one compiling the program, then you are better off providing a self-extracting archive or an installer for your package.

Comment: I wanted to do this when providing an obfuscated test version of a software when working as freelancer, before getting paid. But in my case, I think the easiest solution would be to just change the folder structure in the source code, in addition to making the software unusable after a certain time.

Answer (score 2):

nsis http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System would be the best option I have seen.  I have made several wrappers for work apps that we don't want users poking around the files used to repair their pc etc.  I just built a virus scanner front end this week that auto downloads msert/mcafee stinger/mcafee rootkit using the corp proxy and then runs all 3 apps for the tech's.

you could do what your asking with a standard template/example, in the main section set the out dir [ $OUTDIR %temp%_MEI188722 ]  and add a [ file yourapp.exe  ] line for each file in the original directory that the program needs. next use a execwait  line to run the application in question.  a command for sleep 20ms and then delete %temp%_MEI188722  so that the files get removed after they are not being used.

Setting the installer to silent mode would keep any standard installer dialog boxes from showing up and your app would just load after a moment. or you could create custom dialog pages if you needed the user to select any options first or wanted the app to return a message if it had some kind of error. The tutorials and community are quite active and help full so once you get used to how nsis does things it should be straight forward.  http://hmne.sourceforge.net/  this is a handy program to allow you to more easily edit the script file to allow you to make the exe.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't allow an application to be launched from inside a container (like a zip file) in native way. That's why PyInstaller unpacks to a temporary directory for running the actual application.

Compressors like ZIP and 7Zip offer you the ability to create a self-extracting executable. Which is the regular compressed file plus the executable code needed for decompressing. Packed into a single file. 7zip offers the option to create self-extracting archives for installers. Maybe you can use this option to run a standard program instead of an installer anyway: http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/sfx.htm

You can configure it to run any file you want after extracting. I'm not sure if you are going to be able to remove the prompt.

Comment: 7zip or izarc has the option to automatically run an exe after it extracts the files. they don't delete the files though when they are done. so at best you are leaving behind a bunch of files in the tmp folder and at worst have just showed the user where to find your app and files so they can muck with it.

Comment: According to the link I passed, 7Zip removes temporary folder after execution.

Comment: not if the program is currently running locking a file. I am 90% sure I tried using the sfx with auto delete several years agao for our wrapper and it never properly deleted files.  I ended up making a batch file to delete the files we didn't want the users to know about. If they got better at that I can't say since I use nsis for every thing now.

Comment: "Windows doesn't allow an application to be launched from inside a container" - this is false.  It has nothing to do with *allowing*, its that the program is not executable code until is decompressed.